# How to use Select max and Insert together in pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My goal is to create PL/SQL procedure EditRegion(par_ID int, par_Name varchar2) where If par_ID<>0 then it should (for the existing statement in REGIONS, where REGION_ID=par_ID) update REGION_NAME with the values from par_Name.

and my else should be if par_ID=0 then insert new slog into REGIONS, where REGION_NAME=par_Name, and in REGION_ID number which is for one bigger from the biggest  REGION_ID in the table. I am using this max function I found somewhere online, and I am not sure how to fix this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  EditRegion
AS
par_ID int;
 par_Name VARCHAR2(10) ;
 REGION_ID : = SELECT MAX (REGION_ID),from REGIONS ;
BEGIN
if par_ID<>0 then 
UPDATE regions
  SET REGION_NAME = par_NAME
WHERE REGION_ID = par_ID ;
 else
INSERT into REGIONS 
(REGION_ID,REGION_NAME)
VALUES
(REGION_NAME := par_NAME ,
REGION_ID := REGION_ID +1 );
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Is this procedure supposed to get parameters? Looks like your are not populating `par_ID` and `par_Name`

Comment: No, it is supposed to work independently

Comment: So how would `par_ID` be ever equal to 0? and how would `par_NAME` get any value?

Comment: So you think I should add them some values?

Comment: Don't you thing you have to? Those params are `NULL` until you'll populate them in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  EditRegion(par_NAME in VARCHAR2)
    AS
    par_ID int;
    BEGIN
SELECT MAX(REGION_ID) into par_ID from REGIONS ;
    if par_ID<>0 then 
    UPDATE regions
      SET REGION_NAME = par_NAME
    WHERE REGION_ID = par_ID ;
     else
    INSERT into REGIONS 
    (REGION_ID,REGION_NAME)
    VALUES
    (par_NAME ,
    SELECT MAX(REGION_ID)+1 FROM regions);
    END IF;
    END;
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is what you are looking for,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EditRegion(
    par_ID   INT,
    par_Name VARCHAR2)
AS
  par_ID   INT;
  par_Name VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  IF par_ID<>0 THEN
    UPDATE regions SET REGION_NAME = par_NAME WHERE REGION_ID = par_ID ;
  ELSE
    INSERT
    INTO REGIONS
      (
        REGION_ID,
        REGION_NAME
      )
      VALUES
      (
        par_NAME ,
        (SELECT MAX(REGION_ID)+1 FROM regions
        )
      );
  END IF;
END;
/
```